# Php. show image only if almost one if is true

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to display the div with `".social-border-top"` class only if almost one of PHP "if" in the list is true.

this is the code:

```
<?php  if( $social ) : ?>
      <div class="author-social flat-social" id="author-social">
        <div class="social-border-top" id="social-border-top">
                    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/81967/Old-style-border.png" class="float-right">
                </div>
                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'instagram' , $user_id ) ) : ?>
                <a class="foap-social social-instagram" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'instagram' , $user_id ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'behance' , $user_id ) ) : ?>
                <a class="foap-social social-behance" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'behance' , $user_id ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'pinterest' , $user_id ) ) : ?>
                <a class="foap-social social-pinterest" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'pinterest' , $user_id ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'youtube' , $user_id ) ) : ?>
                <a class="foap-social social-youtube" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'youtube' , $user_id ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'flickr' , $user_id ) ) : ?>
                <a class="foap-social social-flickr" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'flickr' , $user_id ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'linkedin' , $user_id ) ) : ?>
                <a class="foap-social social-linkedin" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'linkedin' , $user_id ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'google' , $user_id ) ) : ?>
                <a class="foap-social social-google-plus" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'google' , $user_id ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter' , $user_id  ) ) : ?>
                <a class="foap-social social-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta( 'twitter' , $user_id ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook' , $user_id ) ) : ?>
                <a class="foap-social social-facebook" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook' , $user_id ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'url' , $user_id ) ) : ?>
                <a class="foap-social social-site" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'url' , $user_id ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I'm tryng with jQuery but not seems to work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if ($(".author-social").html().length = 0) {
     $('.social-border-top').hide();
    }                                           
});
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: What in the world does "if almost one" mean?!?

Comment: your jquery conditional will always be considered as being `0` length.

Comment: @Enstage Sorry, maybe I explained bad my issue. I've the possibility in the theme option to show the social icon if i fill the field with the social profile url. This option is true for every single of this social list above: if i fill the facebook field with my facebook profile URL (for exemple), in the front end the facebook icon is shown, and so on for the others.

I want that `.social-border-top` div is shown if the social icon displayed are > 1, not important what's the social icon, is important that's is visualized an icon of this list.

Hope i'm explaining well.

Answer (score 1):

In your jQuery, you should check for `$('.foap-social').length`, instead of `.author-social`.
Based on your HTML, `$('.author-social')` will always return the container.

And `.html().length = 0` here you should use `== 0` instead of `= 0`

Comment: thank for your reply. I've tried to edit the Jquery code like so

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if (<?php $exist ?>) {
 $('.social-border-top').hide();
}                                           
});`

but still not working. Have you some other tips that can helps me pleas? thanks a lot

Comment: if you want to go with Saad's solution, then you should do it like this:
`jQuery(document).ready(function($){
<?php if ($exist):?>
$('.social-border-top').hide();
<?php endif;?>
});`

Answer (score 1):

you can add a variable in your php to act as boolean inside your if statements

```
<?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'instagram' , $user_id ) ) : ?>
            <a class="foap-social social-instagram" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'instagram' , $user_id ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
$exist=1;
<?php endif ?>
```

and add the php variable into your jquery code like so

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if (<?php echo $exist ?>) {
 $('.social-border-top').hide();
}                                           
});
```

Note remember to declare the exist variable outside if else it will lose its scope

P.S 
Pavel's answere is better for your code but i felt like mentioning this so others that have similar problem can use this

Here is a simple and working implementation to your problem just copy and paste to a php file and it should work like you want

```
<?php
$exist;
?>
<?php if (1):
    $exist=1;?>
    <a class="foap-social social-instagram" href="dsa">Dummy text<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>

<?php endif ?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

if (<?php echo $exist ?>) {
    alert("Now to hide");
$('.foap-social').hide();
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: My bad i forgot to echo i have made the changes